# Confusing supremum of a function question

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be continuous on $D = [a,b]$ where $0<b-a < \infty$

T/F, $f(x) < F^* = supf$(on domain D) $\forall x \in [a,b]$, but there is no $x_0$ in $[a,b]$ where $f(x_0) = F^*$

I do not know where to start with this problem, because it doesn't seem to make any logical sense to me.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying the supremum over the subset $D$...that doesn't seem to make much sense since that would mean the maximum value over that domain.  On the other hand, if $\forall X \in D: f(x) < F*$ then this means the supremum is _outside_ of the domain $D$ (since $f(x): x \in D$ is strictly less than the supremum).

Comment: What tools do you have to work with? Do you know the theorem that a continuous function defined on a compact set achieves a maximum value on that set? If not, you're essentially going to have to prove that theorem, for the special case $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply asking if it is true or false that $f(x) < \sup f ([a,b])$ and never equal.

The way I see it there are three possible awswers:

TRUE. It is always true for all continuous f on all closed intervals.

FALSE. It is never true for any continuous f on any closed interval.

AMBIGUOUS.  It is true for some not for others.

Try a few.  Let $f (x) = 2-x^2$  on [-1,2].  What do you think sup f is.  Does f (x) = sup f ever?  Can you prove the ambiguous case never happens? Or find samples were the statement occurs and another where it doesn't?

Answer (score -1):

Consider the function $f(x) = -1/x$ on the interval $[1, \infty)$.  The supremum of this function is $0$ even though there is no $x$ on the interval such that $f(x) = 0$.  But, this is an open interval, not a closed interval.  The question may have to do with whether or not it is possible for this to be the case for a function defined over a closed interval.

Hint: take a look at the Extreme Value Theorem.